# AppBar in WP7.5 Panorama page

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control, appbar

I'm currently developing a Windows Phone 7.5 app with a panorama page.
At the panorama page, I'm implementing an appbar to deal with several things in the app, such as displaying phone location in a Bing Map which is located in one of the panorama page items.

Now, I believe I have two options, but I don't know how they would work (if they even do work...):

1. Show only appbar icons relevant to current page/item
2. If you're not at the respective page/item, redirect to the page/item when clicking the appbar icon.

Would any of these actually work? Could I set an ID for each of the panorama items, and then make either 1 or 2 to work?

Thanks :)

Comment: As an aside, it may be worth reading [this article on Choosing between Panoramas, Pivots and/or Pages.](http://ux.artu.tv/?p=234)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are possible to accomplish.

For showing only the **appbar icons relevent to the page** you can use the Panorama.SelectionChanged Event:

```
var currentPanormaItem = ((Panorama)sender).SelectedItem

if(currentPanormaItem.Equals(firstPageItem))
{
    // Set AppBar icons for first page
}
else if(currentPanormaItem.Equals(secondPageItem))
{
    // Set AppBar icons for secondpage
}
```

If you know which panorama item is selected you can set the appbar icon accordingly.

**Changing the selected item** of a Panorama can be accomplished like this:

```
panoramaControl.DefaultItem = panoramaControl.Items[indexToSet];
```

Though changing the selected index of a Panorama is possible, I would advise using a Pivot control. With a Pivot control it is easier to keep track of the selected item and you get a nice animation when you programatically switch the selected page.